# Terraform: how to enable VM Insights for Azure Windows VM using Azure Monitor Agent?

Tags: azure, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to enable Insights on my Azure Windows VMs using the Azure Monitor Agent (AMA) but there's not a lot of current sample code for this, most sample uses the deprecated Microsoft Monitoring Agent (MMA).

By configuring Insights in Azure Portal, I've found that it Azure needs:

- a data collection rule
- a destination Log Analytics Workspace
- associate the data collection rule to the VM
- install the DependencyAgentWindows VM extension
- install the AzureMonitorWindowsAgent VM extension

When I replicate this in Terraform, I see entries in the Log Analytics Workspace but there is nothing shown in the VM Insights interface. Azure Monitor recognises that the VM is connected by AMA.

Does anyone have working sample code for VM Insights using AMA and *not* MMA?

Sanitised Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ama" {
  for_each                   = var.windows_vms

  name                       = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitor"
  type                       = "AzureMonitorWindowsAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.14"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.this[each.key].id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "da" {
  for_each                   = var.windows_vms

  name                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  type                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "9.10"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.this[each.key].id
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "vminsights" {
  for_each                    = var.windows_vms

  name                        = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.rule_name
  resource_group_name         = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.rule_rg_name
  location                    = var.region

  data_flow {
    destinations = [ "log-analytics" ]
    streams      = [
      "Microsoft-Event",
      "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics",
      "Microsoft-Perf",
      "Microsoft-ServiceMap"
    ]
  }

  data_flow {
    destinations = [ "monitor-metrics" ]
    streams      = [ "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics" ]
  }

  data_sources {
    extension {
      extension_name     = "DependencyAgent"
      name               = "DependencyAgentDataSource"
      streams            = [ "Microsoft-ServiceMap" ]
    }

    performance_counter {
      counter_specifiers            = [ "\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics" ]
      name                          = "insights-metrics"
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      streams                       = [
        "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics",
        "Microsoft-Perf"
      ]
    }

    windows_event_log {
      name           = "windows-events"
      streams        = [ "Microsoft-Event" ]
      x_path_queries = [
        "Application!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]",
        "System!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"
      ]
    }
  }

  destinations {
    azure_monitor_metrics {
      name = "monitor-metrics"
    }

    log_analytics {
      name                  = "log-analytics"
      workspace_resource_id = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.log_analytics_workspace_id
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule_association" "vminsights" {
  for_each                = var.windows_vms

  name                    = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.rule_association_name
  data_collection_rule_id = azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule.vminsights[each.key].id
  description             = "Monitor data collection rule for ${each.value.name}"
  target_resource_id      = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.this[each.key].id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both Insights Metrics and Insights Map are working with the following changes:

1. Add a settings block to the DependencyAgentWindows extension:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "da" {
  for_each                   = var.windows_vms

  name                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  automatic_upgrade_enabled  = true
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.Monitoring.DependencyAgent"
  settings                   = jsonencode(
{
  "enableAMA" = "true"
}
  )
  type                       = "DependencyAgentWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "9.10"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.this[each.key].id
}
```

2. Removed the DCR destination `azure_monitor_metrics` as per below:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "vminsights" {
  for_each                    = var.windows_vms

  name                        = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.rule_name
  resource_group_name         = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.rule_rg_name
  location                    = var.region

  data_flow {
    destinations = [ "log-analytics" ]
    streams      = [ "Microsoft-Event" ]
  }

  data_flow {
    destinations = [ "log-analytics" ]
    streams      = [ "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics" ]
  }

  data_flow {
    destinations = [ "log-analytics" ]
    streams      = [ "Microsoft-ServiceMap" ]
  }

  # data_flow {
  #   destinations = [ "monitor-metrics" ]
  #   streams      = [ "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics" ]
  # }

  data_sources {
    extension {
      extension_name     = "DependencyAgent"
      name               = "DependencyAgentDataSource"
      streams            = [ "Microsoft-ServiceMap" ]
    }

    performance_counter {
      counter_specifiers            = [ "\\VmInsights\\DetailedMetrics" ]
      name                          = "insights-metrics"
      sampling_frequency_in_seconds = 60
      streams                       = [
        "Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"
      ]
    }

    windows_event_log {
      name           = "windows-events"
      streams        = [ "Microsoft-Event" ]
      x_path_queries = [
        "Application!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]",
        "System!*[System[(Level=1 or Level=2 or Level=3)]]"
      ]
    }
  }

  destinations {
    # azure_monitor_metrics {
    #   name = "monitor-metrics"
    # }

    log_analytics {
      name                  = "log-analytics"
      workspace_resource_id = each.value.vminsights_data_collection.log_analytics_workspace_id
    }
  }
}
```